# Spring Java Based Configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm facing issue in converting xml based bean configuration to Java based bean configuration in Spring MVC project. I need to convert the below xml configuration to Java based by using @ bean. Please help me.. Thanks in advance

```
<bean class="someclass">
  <property name="somename">
    <util:list>
      <bean id="someid"   class="someotherclass"/>
    </util:list>
  </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create the OtherClass bean, like this:

```
@Bean
private SomeClass someclassBean() {
    SomeClass sc = new SomeClass();
    sc.setSomeName(Arrays.asList(new SomeOtherClass()));
    return sc;
}
```

In your specific needs, try this:

```
@Bean
AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter annotationMethodHandlerAdapter() {

    AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter bean = new AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter()
    bean.setMessageConverters(Arrays.asList(new ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter()));
    return bean;
}
```

Comment: No he doesn't. He can just create a new instance of `SomeOtherClass`. The bean definition is an internal one and the id doesn't make sense on those.

Comment: Thanks.... actually this is the one i wanted to convert          <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
  <property name="messageConverters">
    <util:list>
      <bean id="byteArrayMessageConverter"   class="org.springframework.http.converter.ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter"/>
    </util:list>
  </property>
</bean>

Comment: It's the same, only with other names.

Comment: Well actually it is not the same and I wonder why would you want this as this is already one of the default MessageConverters registered. Also you shouldn't use the `AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter` on newer versions of Spring but should use `@EnableWebMvc` and that has also a different way of registering additional converters.